# Replacing a string when it is not followed by string with Sed

Tags: linux, bash, regex, sed

I am looking for a sed script to replace a string when it is not followed by a string in the content of a file.

Currently I am at this approach

```
sed -i -E "s/${filehash}(?!.de)/${filehash}.de/g" "index.html";
```

The script should replace filehash with *filehash*.de when it's not followed by .de already.

Currently the script fails with:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 55: Invalid preceding regular expression
```

I am trying this on Ubuntu.

Comment: AFAIK `sed` doesn't support lookahead. Are you open to a perl solution?

Answer (score 1):

The lookahead regex syntax is not supported in the
[Sed Regular Expression Syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html).

I can't see a way of writing "not regexp" in the above syntax,
so you might need to break it into several operations:

1. `filehash.de` to `whatever`
2. `filehash` to `filehash.de`
3. `whatever` to `filehash.de`

Comment: 0

Absolutely right about alternative angle being relevant. It can in fact be shortened to:

filehash to filehash.de
filehash.de.de to filehash.de